# Keep functions private into a lib in C

Tags: c, dll, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I recently had to face a fairly complex issue regarding lib management, but I would be very surprised to be the first one.

Let's imagine you are creating a library (static or dynamic) called `lib1` in **C**. Inside `lib1` are a few functions that are exposed through an API, and a few other ones which remain private.

Ideally, the private functions would be `static`. Unfortunately, let's assume one of the source files, called `extmod.c`, come from another project, and it would be beneficial to keep it unmodified. Therefore, it becomes unpractical to `static` the functions it defines.

As a consequence, all the functions defined into `extmod` are present into `lib1` ABI, but not the API, since the relevant `*.h` is not shipped. So no one notice.

Unfortunately, at later stage, someone wants to link both `lib1` and another `lib2` which also includes `extmod`. It results in a linking error, due to duplicate definitions.

In `C++`, the answer to this problem would be a simple namespace. In C, we are less lucky.

There are a few solutions to this problem, but I would like to probe if anyone believes to have found an efficient and non-invasive way. By "non-invasive", I mean a method which avoids if possible to modify `extmod.c`.

Among the possible workaround, there is the possibility to change all definitions from `extmod.c` using a different prefix, effectively emulating namespace. Or the possibility to put the content of `extmod.c` into `extmod.h` and static everything. Both method do extensively modify `extmod` though ...

Note that I've looked at [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776912/make-part-of-a-c-lib-private), but it doesn't address this specific concern.

Comment: You don't really need to modify the file by hand, I mean not function by function, I would use `libclang` probably the python bindings and create a new file from the source of `extmod.c` where all functions are static.

Comment: It's not that simple. If functions inside `extmod.c` are made blindly static, not even the library can access them. So it would require additionnal transformations, such as transferring the content of the `.c` into the `.h`, and there your start to inherit a lot more problems, such as naming collisions, unused static code, and so on ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement your 'different prefix' solution by excluding extmod.c from your your build and instead treating it as header file in a way. Use the C pre-processor to effectively modify the file without actually modifying it. For example if extmod.c contains:

```
void print_hello()
{
   printf("hello!");
}
```

Exclude this file from your build and add one called ns_extmod.c. The content of this file should look like this:

```
#define print_hello ns_print_hello
#include "extmod.c"
```

On compilation, print_hello will be renamed to ns_print_hello by the C pre-processor but the original file will remain intact.

Alternatively, IF AND ONLY IF the function are not called internally by extmod.c, it might work to use the preprocessor to make them static in the same way:

```
#define print_hello static print_hello
#include "extmod.c"
```

This should work for you assuming you have control over the build process.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to fully grasp your suggestion, since it seems on good track. Especially I like that it seems to not require modifying initial files.

So now let's assume that we have a file `ns_extmod_c` which, as you suggest, contain a bunch of macro translated symbol names and then includes `extmod.c`.
I guess that a similar transformation must be applied to the `extmod.h` file too, so that prototype definitions coincide.

You last comment on `static` is less clear to me...

Comment: Well, thinking again about it, it seems better to introduce the translating macro at `.h` level. Since the `.h` is included, definitions are automatically transferred to `.c`. Even better, calling programs including the `.h` also get the benefit of the translation for free, so no need to change this side of the code either. Looks like a good win from all side. Now onto practicing ...

Comment: OK, so if we also want to not touch the `.h`, it's necessary to define both a `ns_extmod.c` and a `ns_extmod.h`, and they become the versions called by the user program. The other idea is like @harshad : translated symbol names are into a `.h` which _is included by_ `extmod.h`, and all new names are automatically transferred. But it requires to change one line of code within `extmod.h`. Not a big deal if you ask me, but then it becomes easy to make a mistake in a future update : not modifying `extmod.h` to `#include "ns_extmod.h"` results in original names used gain, creating name collisions.

Comment: The last comment about making them static doesn't make a much sense come to think of it, but I think you are on the right track now! :-)

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do prefixing without actually editing extmod.c is as follows:

Create a new header file extmod_prefix.h as:

```
#ifndef EXTMOD_PREFIX_H
#define EXTMOD_PREFIX_H

#ifdef LIB1
#define PREFIX lib1_
#else
#ifdef LIB2
#define PREFIX lib2_
#endif
#endif

#define function_in_extmod PREFIX##function_in_extmod
/* Do this for all the functions in extmod.c */

#endif
```

Include this file in extmod.h and define **LIB1** in lib1's build process and **LIB2** in lib2.

This way, all the functions in extmod.c will be prefixed by lib1_ in lib1 and lib2_ in lib2.

Comment: This is a very good idea.
Ultimately, I will nonetheless prefer @Shwany method, which is extremely close to the one you suggest. The major difference is that the user program includes the alternate `ns_extmod.h` and compile the alternate `ns_extmod.c` instead of the original ones. The major benefit is long term : in a long time in the future, someone will update `extmod` with a newer version, and may not be aware that it needs to modify a single line within `extmod.h` to call the translated named. It results in a silent issue : original names are now used again, and no one notice, until ...

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092043/transform-c-c-object-symbols) (in the form of a question). The relevant portion:

> `objcopy --prefix-symbols` allows me to prefix all symbols exported by
>   an object file / static library.

Comment: It's a good point. Now, using objcopy also adds one more dependency to the build chain.