# Transform C++/C object symbols

Tags: c++

`objcopy --prefix-symbols` allows me to prefix all symbols exported by an object file / static library.

Can I perform a more sophisticated transformation?

In particular, I would like to be able to add a C++ namespace to an object file / static library, i.e., demangle the symbols, prefix the result, and remangle it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to add the C tag to an apparently C++-only question?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer(s).

### Any transformation(s):

```
objcopy --redefine-sym old=new
objcopy --redefine-syms=filename
```

> --redefine-sym old=new
>              Change the name of a symbol old, to new.  This can be useful when one is trying link two things
>              together for which you have no source, and there are name collisions.
>
> --redefine-syms=filename
>              Apply --redefine-sym to each symbol pair "old new" listed in the file filename.  filename is simply
>              a flat file, with one symbol pair per line.  Line comments may be introduced by the hash character.
>              This option may be given more than once.

### Demangling

```
 c++filt
```

### Mangling

[Getting mangled name from demangled name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400105/getting-mangled-name-from-demangled-name)